# Get the data from the thread

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-platform, ros2

Let me give you a bigger picture of the problem... I am designing a [ROS2-based](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/index.html) system with multiple ROS2 nodes each containing a wrapper part (ROS2 layer) and driver/module part where my low-level logic is implemented. The wrapper part is using some ROS2-specific communication mechanisms ([topics](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Topics/Understanding-ROS2-Topics.html), [services](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.html), [actions](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Understanding-ROS2-Actions.html)...) to exchange the data/commands between the nodes.

[image]

Now, one of the nodes in the system should establish an MQTT connection with the Google Cloud Platform, keep the connectivity alive and allow data exchange between the Cloud and ROS2 system. For that purpose, I am using [iot-device-sdk-embedded-c](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c) SDK from Google.

It has `iotc_connect()` blocking function for establishing and keeping connection with the Cloud so the challenge I am facing with is to simultaneously keep the ROS2 node spinning while keeping MQTT connectivity alive.

My idea was to launch a thread from ROS2 wrapper that will be used for establishing/keeping MQTT connectivity and use a callback function as an argument for the thread function that will enable me to forward the data received from the Cloud ithin the thread directly to ROS2 layer. Launching a separate thread for handling connectivity and data exchange would enable my ROS2 node to properly spin and rest synchronized with the rest of the ROS2 system.

**ROS2_Wrapper.cpp**

```
thread mqtt_thread(MqttConnHandler::ConnectToMqttServer, &MqttThreadCallback);    
mqtt_thread.detach();
...
void MqttThreadCallback(void* data, size_t  size){

}
```

`MqttThreadCallback()` should be called every time I receive the command/config data from the Cloud.

However, I am not sure how can I fire the callback function within the thread because I have two layers of nested callbacks within the thread:

my_thread.cpp

```
ConnectToMqttServer(void (*MqttThreadCallback)(void*, size_t)){
   ...
   iotc_connect(...,&OnConnectionStateChanged);
   ...
}
  
OnConnectionStateChanged(...){
   ...
   case IOTC_CONNECTION_STATE_OPENED:
      iotc_subscribe(...,&iotc_mqttlogic_subscribe_callback,...);
   ...
}

iotc_mqttlogic_subscribe_callback(...){
   //The place where data from the Cloud are received
}
```

`iotc_connect()` contains `OnConnectionStateChanged()` callback from where `iotc_subscribe()` function is called at the moment connection is established. `iotc_subscribe()` contains `iotc_mqttlogic_subscribe_callback()` where data from the Cloud are received.

I am not sure how can I mount the data from `iotc_mqttlogic_subscribe_callback()` up to the thread caller. Do you have any suggestions? Perhaps using the threads is not the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Usually C libraries provide an optional additional argument called user_data for this purpose:

```cpp
extern iotc_state_t iotc_subscribe(iotc_context_handle_t iotc_h,
                                   const char* topic, const iotc_mqtt_qos_t qos,
                                   iotc_user_subscription_callback_t* callback,
                                   void* user_data);
```

That way you can cast your callback function pointer to void when calling subscribe and catch it as argument in the iotc_mqttlogic_subscribe_callback function call. Where you should recast the data back to the function pointer type and use it.

In addition, you may find yourself in need to pass more data to the callback (mutex to protect the data, loggers from higher level code...). In that case, the best practice is to wrap all this info in a new class of your choice and pass a pointer to the instance in the callback.